# How to ignore unknown fields in Spring Boot's ServerProperties?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application (using version 1.2.5.RELEASE) which is working perfectly fine when I run it locally using `SpringApplication`. However, in production the application needs to run as a WAR in a standalone Tomcat. With a properly configured `SpringBootServletInitializer` this works as well.

The problems start when I add a [Context Parameter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) for the WAR with the name `server_names`. Spring Boot tries to configure its `ServerProperties` and picks the parameter up, resulting in the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'names' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Bean
>   property 'names' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does
>   the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

The parameter is defined in an `<application>.xml` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` (see [Defining a context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)). It needs to be there and I don't want to change its name. Is there a way to make Spring Boot ignore unknown fields for its `ServerProperties`?

Comment: Which tool are you using to build your project? If maven, this problem could be easily solved declaring two different profiles, one for production and other for development. Then, just tell maven to include the context.xml with the parameter only for production profile.

Comment: The problem is occurring in production. AFAIK, it will occur in any environment as long as the `server_names` property is there.

Comment: OK, I was misleaded by this sentence: `the WAR's context.xml`.

Comment: I updated my question and hope the problem is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Since Spring Boot 1.2.6.RELEASE `ignoreUnknownFields` on `ServerProperties` is set to `true` by default (see issue [#3903](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3903)), fixing my problem.

Originally (for Spring Boot < 1.2.6.RELEASE), I solved my problem by extending `ServerProperties` and setting `ignoreUnknownFields` to `true`:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
        return new IgnoreUnknownFieldsServerProperties();
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
    public static class IgnoreUnknownFieldsServerProperties extends ServerProperties {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: you're probably using `1.3.0.M4` and we fixed that in `1.3.0.M5`

Check [this issue for more details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3775)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm actually using 1.2.5.RELEASE. Also note that I'm neither using an environment variable nor a system property but a ServletContext init parameter.